# How to recover Audio files from a External HDD?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, data-recovery, external-hdd, testdisk

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for everyday use, from coding to watching movie.

I have a Dell's 1TB External Hard Drive. Where I organize all my files.

In this Hard Drive there is a Directory 'Audio Music' and within this Directory there is another Directory 'Classical/Western Classical'. But all the Directories and Files within this directory disappeared by itself. I didn't delete them, I didn't move them they just vanished. I can't see anything in that directory.

When I tried to see it on Windows 7, I couldn't open the directory and Message was that the 'Directory is Corrupted'. When I logged back in my Ubuntu and tried to create a file in that directory a message appeared (*Snapshot of the error message : that I cannot create a file in that directory.*

[image]

Everything except that directory in Hard Drive is working fine it's just that particular directory where all my audio files vanished. I tried recovering them with testdisk utility but no luck at all, 60 GB space in my home directory got filled with useless text files and videos so I had to stop it.
I just have to recover those audio files because I cannot survive after knowing that all my collection of Classical Music is gone.
Can anyone help me here, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: What FS is on the disk?

Comment: @Jan File System on the HDD is FAT16.

Answer (score 0):

You already tried `testdisk` which would have been my first idea, too.

If it's a question of life and death ("I cannot survive"), you need to pony up some hard ca$h and take the broken disk to a professional recovery service. Beware, this might cost quite a lot (we're taking several hunderds to thousands here).

Advice (this is free): Always. Make. Backups.

Comment: Thanks, But that was supposed to be backup that is why it was on External HDD. I didn't know that something like this can happen. I will survive but I just have to download 30-40 GBs all over again.

Comment: I see... I meant *backup* in the proper sense that you duplicate the data somewhere else. I case you lose the data from the first hdd, it's still on the second (hdd, tape, stick, whatever).